# Coalesce for fetching ids

Tags: sql-server, coalesce

Here is the coalesce function I want to use to fetch all the contract ids separated by comma with contract title in where clause.

```
declare @tempContractID int
 SELECT @tempContractID = COALESCE(@tempContractID,'') + ContractID + ','
   FROM Icn_Contracts where title like '%t'

    select @tempContractID as allcontrcats
```

But I get this error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value ',' to data type int.

When I use coalesce for fetching contract names then it does not show any error.

Comment: Why are you declaring an int but then building a comma-separated string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
declare @tempContractID VARCHAR(MAX); -- you can't build a string as an int

 SELECT @tempContractID = COALESCE(@tempContractID,'') 
   + CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),ContractID) -- needs to be a string, as error says
   + ',' FROM dbo.Icn_Contracts -- please always use schema prefix
   where title like '%t';

    select @tempContractID as allcontrcats;
```

Though I prefer this method because, if you want to rely on the order of the output, you can (if you add an `ORDER BY` to the above query, the resulting order is still undefined).

```
SELECT @tempContractID = STUFF((SELECT ',' 
  + CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), ContractID)
  FROM dbo.Icn_Contracts
  WHERE title LIKE '%t'
  ORDER BY ContractID -- well-defined
  FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value(N'./text()[1]', N'nvarchar(max)'),1,1,'');
```